# Pulling thumbnails and metadata for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web-scraping

Im trying to add something like facebook "status box" to my site, but just with the links functionality.
To be clear, I want my site to automaticlly create a post with title, description and image (meta tags), when someone is sharing a link.
I used wp-web-scraper but it just scrapes data, you cannot create posts using this tool. So does anyone knows of away or tool that can help me achieve this?
Im just going to depend on meta-tags when scraping websites, so its suppose to be more simple no?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Within your `FB.ui()` function add a response method that posts (either AJAX or jut normal HTTP POST) back to itself:

```
function(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                var form = document.createElement('form');
                form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
                form.setAttribute('name', 'cpnfrm');
                var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
                hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'key');
                hiddenField.setAttribute('value', g);
                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();
            }
```

Where g is some sort of value (perhaps an array of data for your script). From this I'd say check for valid POSTs in your script and use that to create a post, rudamentiary example:

```
if(!empty($_POST['key']){
    $post = array(
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'post_name' => 'name',
        'post_title' => 'title',
        'post_content' => 'content'
    );
    $inserted = wp_insert_post($post);
    // add_post_meta($inserted, 'meta_key', 'meta_value');
}
```

You can use the response of wp_insert_post as the id. If it fails it should return false.
Note that this won't be all ready to rock, you'll still need to put some catches in to detect anyone messing around with the js but it should be a starting point.

Hope this helps.